# VOIP Using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, voip, ionic-framework

Is there's anyway I can implement VOIP Client using Ionic Framework ?
Theres a SDK for the VOIP but regarding the connection and everything, is it possible or should I go native ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why you can't do the UI in phonegap (or ionic) but a lot of the  VOIP functionality would probably need to be native implemented as a phonegap plugin.

Comment: @RipRyness I need an example or something that will help if any, thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to use VOIP SDK's in Javascript. These SDK's rely on WebRTC to work, and this is not always available in older Android versions for example. These frameworks are however stable enough to work in a browser on your desktop.

You have several complications with Cordova instead of native. In Javascript you have a lot less control on connection and the OS in general. For example: when you are using VOIP and the phone goes on standby, you will lose connection because on iOS cannot run on the background with Cordova. Android has some ways of running in the background but you will have to experiment if this works when you are using VOIP.

In short: You will never get an as stable version of VOIP in Cordova as you could get native because the support in the browser still lacks support. If you want the best user experience for VOIP you will have to use native components (for now).

As alternative, you have a Cordova plugin [phono](http://phono.com/mobile) that will let you make VOIP calls from your Cordova app. This is a plugin that I found searching on the internet and haven't tried it myself. There may be other Cordova plugins that work better.

Answer (score 3):

You have three options:

1. use existing native SDKs and connect them to your phonegap application
2. go completely native
3. use WebRTC

Option 3 is not recommended(I agree with points @Ricconnect made in his answer).

If you choose option 1 or 2, you can use existing libraries, e. g. [Twilio mobile client](https://www.twilio.com/client/mobile). And you can then connect the native library to your app(option 1) with [phonegap plugin](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap)(or you create your own connector).

My recommendation would be option 1 and I would also suggest you also read [this post](http://www.jefflinwood.com/2013/07/android-phonegap-plugin-for-twilio-client/)(written by the Author of before mentioned plugin).

Comment: for your explaination, I was wondering, have you tried this yourself ?

Comment: Hi @Axil I am looking for the best option in 2019 :-) Do you have suggestions?

Comment: i'ved shelved the idea but nevertheless, i too looking for the best option, do update if you have any good suggestion.  i think i explored some of it previously, there is always some drawbacks...i'd like to know current offerings

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use VOIP SDK's in Javascript. These SDK's rely on WebRTC to work, and this is not always available in older Android versions for example. These frameworks are however stable enough to work in a browser on your desktop.

Hi,
Yes it it is possible to use voip with Javascript, because javascript have a lot of features that can enable the pop-up in the web portal. these are the thimng that are stable enough to work the voip for ***small office phone systems*** and working on destop using ***VoIP Telephone System***.