# I want VoIP feature to my app in cordova

Tags: cordova, voip

I am using VoIP background mode to wake up the app and update database in the IOS. But I am not having any VoIP feature in my app. Can you please suggest me any plugin or method to implement VoIP feature in ionic platform? Thank you.

Comment: That's a really big ask; the list of plugins that we have wrappers for are here: http://ngcordova.com; you should check the cordova plugins and see if one does what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214435/voip-using-phonegap