# Changing voice using Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building a voip calling app for android using apache cordova and ionic framework with angular2, my question is how to change the pitch of the voice during call and how to add background voice also with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such Cordova plugin, [nor is it likely to ever be one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28281802/5015955).

While Cordova is good for most applications, what you are looking for is called signal processing and is a very low level, highly mathematical set of procedures that is only suited for native app development.

**I strongly suggest you reconsider your approach, or design in general.**

Sorry to be a buzzkill.

Comment: So is there away calling third party plugins or libraries designed for android from cordova?

Comment: You can use existing libraries, e. g. [Twilio mobile client](https://www.twilio.com/client/mobile). And you can then connect the native library to your app with [this phonegap plugin](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap), or you create your own cordova plugin with the twillio SDK.